# Previous button in Android application

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am developing a simple Android application. I have a fragment with two buttons: prev and home. If I touch home it works fine (back to the main menu) but I must touch twice the prev button if I want to back to the previous activity. I don't know what is going on. I searched but nothing. Has anyone got the same problem?

Thanks for help.

Here my code:

```
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                       Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.navigation_activity_fragment, container, false);
TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.activityTitle);
Button home = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.home);
Button prev = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button2);

home.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(),  MainMenuActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
                }

});
prev.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        getActivity().finish();
                }

});


return view;
 }
```

and xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/screen_header"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/screen_header"
android:contentDescription="@null"/>

<TextView
  android:id="@+id/activityTitle"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/screen_header"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
  android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
  android:text="Large Text"
  android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
  android:textColor="@color/black"
  android:textSize="16.5dip"
  android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
  android:id="@+id/home"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/activityTitle"
  android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/activityTitle"
  android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
  android:background="@drawable/home_btn" 
  android:onClick="onClick"/>

<Button
  android:id="@+id/button2"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/activityTitle"
  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
  android:background="@drawable/prev_btn" 
  android:onClick="onClick"/>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: Some UI element has retained focus. That's why the first back seem to not do anything, when in fact you're giving away the focus

Comment: There is finish() in fragments.
click onBackPressed

Answer (score 0):

This is a general way to do  -

You have to add fragments to the transaction whenever you need to display them in a UI.

For instance -

From `Fragment A`, to go to `Fragment B`, [replace](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace%28int,%20android.support.v4.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String%29) `A with B` and use [addToBackstack()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html#addToBackStack%28java.lang.String%29) before [commit()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#commit%28%29).

Now From Fragment B, just use `popBackStack()`, this will bring back A.

```
prev.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();

                }
});
```

For your code particularly not sure but this is not the correct way to go back to the previous fragment. When you do `getActivity().finish()`, you are finishing the current activity rather then going back to the previous fragment. Please note that when your each activity have a single fragment then what you tried seems correct but if your activity contains many fragments and you perform finish on it then it will switch you back to the previous activity.

So in order to enable the navigation for fragments, you have to add them to [backstack](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#addToBackStack%28java.lang.String%29).

Then to go back to previous fragment just use [popBackStack](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#popBackStack%28%29).